# What is the best way to update elements into an observable array?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I see two options:

```
#1 observable_array.replace() ?
```

or

```
#2 observable_array=[ ] ?
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should favor the first according to [the documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html)

The problem with overriding the array is that you will lose the `observable` property if you don't override the observable array with a new observable array.

In the end, when setting an observable array, mobx observes changes for each entry of the array, not changes on the array object itself.